# compile issue with apache 2.4.33 and openssl 1.1.0h

Tags: apache, openssl

I am trying to compile Apache 2.4.33 with OpenSSL 1.1.0h. But i keep getting this error message. I have been trying to go pass this issue for last 2 weeks. Can you please advice what i should be doing here ?

`

```
libapr-1.la -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -lm -lssl -lcrypto -luuid -lrt -lcrypt -lthread
ab.c: In function `ssl_print_cert_info’:
ab.c:649 undefined reference to `X509_get_version’
ab.c:651 undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore’
ab.c:655 undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter’
ab.c:571 undefined reference to `SSL_in_init’
ab.c:571 undefined reference to `SSL_is_server
x509.h:97 undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num’
x509.h:97 undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value’
ab.c:1941 undefined reference to `SSL_in_init`

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2] *** [ab] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory ‘/apps/httpdx64/http-2.4.33/support’
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory ‘/apps/httpdx64/httpd-2.4.33/support’
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Version of OpenSSL may be too new. Download the source for apr and apr-util from the official website and extract to a folder such as /usr/src. Try compiling Apache with the following to verify if your version of openssl is good or even an issue:

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/src/apr-1.6.3 --with-apr-util=/usr/src/apr-util-1.6.1
make
make install
```